# Extract, transform, and load Excel files

Tags: excel, r, etl

I am curious to know if there is a cleaner/better way to write this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I do ask some questions in comments within the code specific to certain functions/lines of code.

What the Code does:

1. Import files from Excel as `character`
2. Creates a nested tibble/data frame (two columns worth); column 1 makes up the names of the excel files and column 2 a list of tibbles data frames tied to each file name of column 1
3. `Unnest()` tibble so there is one large data frame with all data and all file names in its own column (this unnesting would not have worked as some column data in column 2's tibbles were `double` and others were 'character' - not sure how else I could have worked around this other than importing everything as `character` strng
4. Splits/adds some column data then runs some conditional checking and creates a separate data frame of bad data - bad data is then removed from good data frame (original dataframe)
5. Writes both data frames in specific column order to excel files and two specified folders

The Code:

```
########## CAPTURE FILE DATA

files2 <- 
  list.files(path = "path",pattern = "*xls", full.names = TRUE) %>% basename() # Base name instead

data <- tibble(Customer = files2) %>% # create a data frame
  # holding the file names
  mutate(file_contents = map(Customer,          # read files into
                             ~ read_excel(file.path("path", .), col_types = "text")) # a new data # column and convert to text
  )  

test <- data %>% # Unnest
  unnest(cols = file_contents)

######################################## BEGIN CLEAN        

test <- test %>% # Extract into new column any 5 digit number sequence 
  mutate(order_number = str_extract_all(Customer,"[0-9]{5}"), Customer = str_remove_all(Customer,"SO.*|[[:punct:]]") %>% 
           trimws(), .after = 1) %>% 
  unnest(cols = SO)

# I add columns here because sometimes people add columns not needed or might misspell
# and I can add extras then apply naming conventions across all column headers and only output what I # need
test <- test %>% add_column(new1 = NA, new2 = NA, new3 = NA, .after = names(test[,ncol(test)])) %>%
  add_column(Date = as.character(today(), "%m/%d/%Y"),SourceFile = NA, .after = names(test[,13]))
  
names(test)[1:5] <- c("CUSTOMER","order_number","insert_text1","insert_text2","insert_text3")

# For this Section - I'd love to know if there's a way to, as I write from test to test2, that it removes what is written from test so that I don't have to do separate remove functions in the next code chunk. 
test2 <- test[0,colnames(test)]
test2 <- test[nchar(test$insert_text1) != 10 | 
                grepl(pattern = "text1", x = test$insert_text2`, ignore.case = T) == FALSE | 
                grepl(pattern = "text2", x = test$insert_text3, ignore.case = T) == TRUE |
                is.na(test$insert_text1),]

test <- test[-c(nchar(test$insert_text1) != 10 | 
                  is.na(test$insert_text1) |
                  grepl(pattern = "text2", x = test$insert_text2, ignore.case = T) == TRUE |
                  grepl(pattern = "text1", x = test$insert_text1, ignore.case = T) == FALSE) == FALSE,] # On this last `grepl` I do not understand how the last FALSE logical is making an impact - but #without it, the code does not separate correctly. Can't I just omit the second FALSE logical and turn the False in the `grepl` to TRUE? I tried this and it did not work.

############################ OUTPUT FILE

write_xlsx(test[, c(3:15,1,2,16,17)], path = file.path("good/good.xlsx"))
write_xlsx(test2[,c(3:15,1,2,16,17)], path = file.path("bad/bad.xlsx"))
```